# Blackberry call method after viewing call log history?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mobile, integration

I want to stop a thread process, just after viewing the call history item, for that i need to initialize a method, after viewing call history.

Comment: Hi Mintu. several advices: it's better to ask question in question, not in title, if you solve issue, than accept your answer (press on big check image on the left side of your answer, so it became green), if you giving answer, be more detailed and code will be the best answer if it's possible. Also links to API documentation or articles are very usefull. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes I itself solve it by implementing [PhoneLogListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/PhoneLogListener.html) Interface and call my method inside its method.